# Pronunciation of Middle English phrases "clerkes finden", "the appil take ben", and "that appil take was"

Tags: pronunciation, middle-english

In Britten's "Deo Gracias" (from *A Ceremony of Carols*) there are a few sentences and words which I don't really know how to pronounce:

- clerkes finden
- the appil take ben
- that appil take was

Comment: Do you want to pronounce them the way Benjamin Britten pronounced them, or the way they were pronounced in Middle English?

Comment: Pronounce them as if they were IPA, except _c_ = /k/ and _th_ = /θ/ or /ð/. The vowels should be as in Italian or Spanish. Yes, it won't sound much like English. Middle English didn't. It looks like English because English spelling didn't change when English pronunciation did.

Comment: I would add that syllabic final e is more a schwa sound, but final e can be silent instead of syllabic when meter requires.

Answer (score 3):

I think the Middle English pronunciations of these are more or less like this:

- clerkes finden [ˈklerkəs ˈfiːndən]
- the appil take ben [ðə ˈapːəl ˈtaːkə ˈbeːn]
- that appil take was [ðat ˈapːəl ˈtaːkə ˈwas]

Wikipedia ([Adam lay ybounden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_lay_ybounden)) gives the original spelling of these lines as follows:

- "As clerkes fyndyn wretyn"
- "Ne hadde the appil take ben,"
- "that appil take was!"

The vowel qualities are of course approximate: for example, Middle English short /e/ may have been mid-high, mid-low or true mid, as there is no phonemic contrast between these.

I don't know how it is usually sung in modern performances.

The voicing of word-final and word-initial fricatives is a somewhat uncertain point: there was not much of an established contrast in Middle English between the sounds [ð] and [θ] or [z] and [s] in this context, so "clerkes" might have been [ˈklerkəs] or [ˈklerkəz], "was" might have been [was] or [waz] and "that" might have been [ðat] or [θat].

Long consonants (written double) were simplified at some point in Middle English. I'm also not sure whether the "i" in "finden" was lengthened yet.

Comment: Superb to have it in IPA, so we know how to interpret each letter! I'm surprised to see you lengthen the vowel in the definite article ðeː . Is that correct? It seems odd to me that such an extremely high frequency word as "the" would be given a lengthened vowel. I normally imagine such words are unstressed and shortened.

Comment: @StephenF: I was just looking over this answer and wondering why I wrote "ðeː" there.

Comment: `ðeː appəl`  The [e] would glide into the [a] of apple, lengthening the vowel of ðe.

Comment: @TimR: Oh, that could be. I'm not really sure whether "the" in Middle English had different pronunciations depending on whether it was followed by a vowel.

Comment: I assume the lengthening of the vowel of 'the' when it is elided with a vowel produced farther back in the throat has been a part of the language for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

In the versions I've seen there is an accent on the second 'e' of 'clerkes' and also on the 'e' of 'take', indicating that the letter should be pronounced (i.e. not silent as in modern English). 'Clerk' is of course pronounced 'clark' in British English.

As far as I know 'finden' is simply 'find' with an extra syllable added.

I'm sure there must be recordings on YouTube you could listen to.

Comment: In the cathedral versions I have heard, *clerk* is pronouced like French *clerc*, and *finden* like 'Finn-den". *Clerkes* and *take* must definitely be two syllables, for the scansion; but beyond that I think 'correct pronunciation' for a modern performance of a 1940s version of a 15th-century poem is a matter of opinion.